# ui-sref with a zero padded lead gets truncated

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an old angularjs project that I needed to make some changes to and happen upon this issue.

I have this ui-sref link, where dynamicParam can often lead with a 0.

`<a ui-sref="mystate({query: {{vm.dynamicParam}}})">anchor</a>`

But the rendered link get the lead zero removed.

`<a ui-sref="mystate({query: 058899112112})" href="/mystate/?query=58899112112">anchor</a>`

Can I ensure that the href will include the leading 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your {{vm.dynamicParam}} is a number, you should convert dynamic param to string by using .toStirng() function or by adding "" at the end of your dynamic param where you set it inside your controller. As another option inside your html you can use ng-init which would call a function that would convert your dynamic param int to string or you can directly call that function from your ui-sref.

Comment: But is it, if I debug and look at the actual variable it is a string, and has a 0 at the start. It is also rendered that way in the browser when you look at the ´ui-sref´ like I show above, so if is a matter of it being cast to a number, it seems to happen in the ui-sref directive.

Comment: you can easily test this by removing {{vm.dynamicParam}} and placing 058899112112 and '058899112112' to see what happens.

Comment: ok managed by adding the unicode for the " ´<a ui-sref="mystate({query: &#x22;{{vm.dynamicParam}}&#x22;})">anchor</a>´ , not sure if there was a better way. Maybe there is a filter that wraps result in "

Comment: I'm glad I could help